# 9-Patch in Selector shows black dots

Tags: android, android-xml, nine-patch, android-selector

I want to change the background of a layout when it's pressed.  The layout isn't always the same shape, so I created a 9-patch image that will keep the image centered.  My image looks like this:

[image]

Then my selector xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <item 
     android:state_pressed="true" 
     android:drawable="@drawable/my_selector" 
     />
 <item>
     <shape android:shape="rectangle">
         <solid android:color="#00ffffff" />
     </shape>
 </item>
</selector>
```

When I had this code and my image was not a 9-patch it stretched to fill.  Even though I changed the image to a 9-patch, it still treats the image as a normal .png file.  Even has the black dots in the corner and everything.

[image]

I am wondering why the 9-patch-ness of the image isn't being respected and it's just being treated as a regular .png file.

Comment: Is your 9-patch png file is in the format of: image.9.png?

Comment: Can you upload the actual .9.png file?

Comment: The images I have above are the actual images... is there a better/different way to upload it?  I can host the image somewhere else name and all if you like.

Comment: I just noticed that SO changes the name of the file, but yes the name of the file in my src ends in .9.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you are using two dots on the bottom and right portions of the image. I'm not sure that they system knows how to handle disjoint areas on those two dimensions. You are, in essence, saying the 'content' portion of this image is made up of four one pixel regions which is the intersection of the four dots on the right and bottom borders.

If you take that out, I think it should stretch a lot more predictably for you.

Comment: Nick wins!  I didn't realize that the dots on the right and bottom side of a 9 patch are the (optional) padding area, not the stretching area of the image.  I guess I should just read docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch